# Data Preparation for training

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, data-processing, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to prepare the data file by creating one hot encoding of the text of characters using which I can later train my model for classification. I have a training data file which consists of lines of characters and I am doing initially the integer encoding of them and then the one hot encoding.

e.g. this is how the data file looks:

1. afafalkjfalkfalfjalfjalfjafajfaflajflajflajfajflajflajfjaljfafj
2. fgtfafadargggagagagagagavcacacacarewrtgwgjfjqiufqfjfqnmfhbqvcqvfqfqafaf
3. fqiuhqqhfqfqfihhhhqeqrqtqpocckfmafaflkkljlfabadakdpodqpqrqjdmcoqeijfqfjqfjoqfjoqgtggsgsgqr

This is how I am approaching it:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

categorical_data = pd.read_csv('abc.txt', sep="\n", header=None)
labelEncoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X = categorical_data.apply(labelEncoder.fit_transform)
print("Afer label encoder")
print(X.head())

oneHotEncoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
oneHotEncoder.fit(X)

onehotlabels = oneHotEncoder.transform(X).toarray()
print("Shape after one hot encoding:", onehotlabels.shape)

print(onehotlabels)
```

I am getting the integer encoding for each line (0,1,2 in my case) and then the subsequent one hot encoded vector.

My question is that how do I do it for each character in an individual line as for prediction, the model should learn from the characters in one line( which corresponds to a certain label). Can someone give me some insight on how to proceed from there?

Comment: So you want each line to be one hot encoded independent of all others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example I end up with a DataFrame like so:

```
    0
0   0
1   1
2   2
```

From your description it sounds like you want each line to have its own independent one hot encoding. So lets first look at line 1.

```
afafalkjfalkfalfjalfjalfjafajfaflajflajflajfajflajflajfjaljfafj
```

The reason you are getting the dataframe I included above is that this line is getting read into the DataFrame and then passed to the `labelEncoder` and `oneHotEncoder` as a single value, not an array of 63 values (the length of the string).

What you really want to do is pass the `labelEncoder` an array of size 63.

```
data = np.array([let for let in categorical_data[0][0]])
X = labelEncoder.fit_transform(data)
oneHotEncoder.fit(X.reshape(-1,1))
row_1_labels = oneHotEncoder.transform(X.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
row_1_labels

array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

You could repeat this for each row to get the independent one hot encodings. Like so:

```
one_hot_encodings = categorical_data.apply(lambda x: [oneHotEncoder.fit_transform(labelEncoder.fit_transform(np.array([let for let in x[0]])).reshape(-1,1)).toarray()], axis=1)
one_hot_encodings

                                                    0
0   [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0....
1   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
2   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
```

If you wanted the rows to be one hot encoded based on the values found in all rows you would just first fit the `labelEncoder` to all of the unique letters and then do the transformations for each row. Like so:

```
unique_letters = np.unique(np.array([let for row in categorical_data.values for let in row[0]]))
labelEncoder.fit(unique_letters)
unique_nums = labelEncoder.transform(unique_letters)
oneHotEncoder.fit(unique_nums.reshape(-1,1))
cat_dat = categorical_data.apply(lambda x: [np.array([let for let in x[0]])], axis=1)
one_hot_encoded = cat_dat.apply(lambda x: [oneHotEncoder.transform(labelEncoder.transform(x[0]).reshape(-1,1)).toarray()], axis=1)
one_hot_encoded

                                                    0
0   [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
1   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
2   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
```

This will return you a DataFrame with each row containing the one hot encoded array of letters based on the letters from all rows.

Comment: "From your description it sounds like you want each line to have its own independent one hot encoding". Isn't this approach right, provided 1 line corresponds to a label and I will classify the test data based on the prepared data(as per my approach) that I will feed to the model for training? Or am I approaching it in a wrong way?

Comment: one_hot_encoded = cat_dat.apply(lambda x: oneHotEncoder.transform(labelEncoder.transform(x[0]).reshape(-1,1)).toarray()], axis=1) gives a ValueError: ('X has different shape than during fitting. Expected 26, got 1.', u'occurred at index 0'). Also, there is an extra square bracket in this line.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to say without more context of what you are doing. In general if all of the lines were to be used as training data, they should all be transformed in the same way rather than uniquely for each observation.

Comment: Per your second comment, the beginning bracket of the list comprehension was missing, and the oneHotEncoder should have been fit to unique_num.reshape(-1,1). I updated the code block to reflect this.

Comment: I agree with your comment that "all of the lines were to be used as training data, they should all be transformed in the same way". That's why I am doing the integer(label) encoding on the basis of unique letters in all the rows and then doing the one hot encoding. Another option can be that  I define an alphabet of may be all the lower case characters and then do the integer encoding accordingly.